# "I made a request for a letter be sent to you" or "I made a request for a letter to be sent to you"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am more familiar with using the verb form of request with the imperative, e.g.:

> I requested that a letter be sent to you.

How should I phrase a sentence with the same meaning with the noun?

> I made a request for a letter be sent to you.
>
> I made a request for a letter to be sent to you.
>
> I made a request for a letter sent to you.

Comment: Why would you want to turn your neat example using **request** as a verb into a clumsy sentence using it as a noun?

Comment: @RonaldSole I see possible contexts that call for the use of the noun. _I have seen his request for a letter sent to you._

Answer (score 1):

As @ronaldsole mentions your original wording is pretty much the best.

That said you can say

> I made a request for a letter sent to you.

But it means something different namely there is some organization that has letter sent to you and I requested one of them.

> I made a request for a letter be sent to you.

Is ungrammatical. You could use "that" instead of "for" and that would fix it. It still sounds a bit formal/archaic to me, due to the "be sent to you".

> I made a request for a letter to be sent to you.

Sounds clumsy but I don't think it's ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with Ronald Sole. But if the "request" is a formal thing, you might want to make **request** a noun:

> I submitted a request to the Bureau of Flood Management ...